# Multiple database management

Tags: mongodb, haxe, microservices

I'm currently working on a multiplayer game which will be using two databases(MONGODB). One for authentication(login) and one to contain all game-specific data.
What I've done is to separate the user and game specific data. This way i'll be able to build micro services around the user in the future.

I'm a bit uncertain on how to handle/validate the game-specific database operations tho.
When i log into my game, i perform a POST request to my rest api, which validates the user and returns some data.

The game itself however, is using a TCP socket connection to handle real-time gameplay and will be saving game-specific data to the database on the authoritative server(all game logic is done on the server) . How would you go about to link the data on the game-specific database to a specific user found in the authentication database?

Comment: Users have ids, don't they? So store the user id.

Comment: I can't access the ID that is found in the authentication db from the game-specific db unless i send it through the client which means that the client would be able to tamper with the ID or am i mistaken?.

Comment: Store it in a tamper-proof format. Like encrypted cookies in browsers. Your auth server generates auth data, encrypts it with game server's public key and returns to the client. The client sends this opaque value with each request. Game server decrypts it with its private key and retrieves the user id. Or you can even use symmetric crypto here, for the speed.

Comment: Symmetric Crypto seems like the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: This question is off-topic, as it's broad and opinion-soliciting.

Comment: Can you access both databases from server? That way you would ensure the data are not tampered with by client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, the best option is to not share data, only unique identifiers (primary keys).

In practice, you should not divide the data this way. Part of the user belongs to the game, other parts might be shared across different games. I'm assuming that's why you separated the two.

Have a look at the DDD principle of Bounded Contexts and how you should/could create separate services this way. That being said, defining bounded contexts the proper way is the hardest thing to do in SOA and/or microservices.

Comment: Well, yes and no. I'm dividing the user / game to be able to implement things such as user profiles, authenticator(for 2-step verificaton) in a mobile application. The user profile will have to be shared over multiple games and micro services.  

Thank you for taking your time to answer.